# sudo pecl install apc error on os x lion

Tags: php, osx-lion, apc, osx-mavericks, pecl

I tried installing APC with pecl on OS X Lion (`sudo pecl install apc`) and it complained about a missing pcre.h file:

```
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:44:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found
#include "pcre.h"
```

So I used MacPorts to install the pcre package (`sudo port install pcre`) but it still complains. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think this is because MacPorts installs the header files in a different location from where `pecl` expects them.

To fix this error, I symlinked `pcre.h` to `/usr/include`:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/pcre.h /usr/include/
```

When running `sudo pecl install apc` it compiled just fine.

Comment: This still works for Mavericks. I had the same problem, Googled it, and found my own answer :D

Comment: Works on Mountain Lion (10.8.5) too.

Comment: This worked for me when installing "sudo pecl install imagick" on mac Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 15):

"brew install pcre" worked for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me on OS X, thanks. Hard to say which of above is easier.