# Installing Alternative PHP Cache using PECL and Fink

Tags: php, header-files, apc, pecl, fink

I would like install the Alternative PHP Cache (APC) on my mac.

With PECL this is supposedly a rather painless operation.

All one needs to do is:

`sudo pecl install apc`

As others have reported on the interwebs, `apc` depends on `pcre`, the PHP compatible regular expression library.

Now I've installed the latest version of PHP and PEAR/PECL using fink. I've also installed `pcre` using fink:

```
i   pcre                     8.21-2             Perl Compatible Regular Expressions Library
```

The problem is, when trying to use `sudo pecl install apc`, `pecl` is checking the default directories for the `pcre` libraries and not looking in `/sw`:

```
cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootPtlYda/APC-3.1.13/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootPtlYda/APC-3.1.13/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/APC -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/APC/apc.c:45:
/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:10: fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found
#include "pcre.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Hence I have two questions:

1. Is there an environment variable I can set to point to the fink `pcre` libraries for compiling `apc`?
2. Where exactly is fink even putting `pcre`?

**UPDATE**

I see this question regarding Macports:

[sudo pecl install apc error on os x lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767983/sudo-pecl-install-apc-error-on-os-x-lion)

In this question, the answer involves symlinking the needed `pcre` headers to their expected location for PECL.

I tried a similar solution. For the fink approach, the symlink command here is:

`sudo ln -s /sw/include/pcre.h /usr/include/`

But still this did not work. The installation of APC via PECL does not seem to be able to find this header file.

And I should add, indeed, the `pcre.h` header file is found in `/sw/include/pcre.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found the answer.

Inspecting the file that is expecting `pcre.h` (`/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29`) I see this:

`#include "pcre.h"`

Perhaps there is a way to add an include path during a PECL installation, but I am unaware of how to do so.

My solution then was to simply place the symlink to `pcre.h` in the directory containing this offending source file. Like so:

`sudo ln -s /sw/include/pcre.h /usr/include/php/ext/pcre/`

That did it. Maybe folks have a more elegant way to do this but for others with this problem, this should get the job done.

**VERY IMPORTANT UPDATE**

Actually, I should note that my above information is incomplete and **will not** work.

The problem is, one must be certain to first install the fink package **php5-dev**.

Frankly, I think the fink package `php-pear` should be made to have `php5-dev` as a dependency. It does not, and I for the moment am not familiar in maintaining fink packages so this will have to do.

The consequences of **not** having this package is simply that the requisite header files needed when compiling `APC` are not available for  fink version of php. They are, fortunately or unfortunately, available for the Mountaion Lion included PHP. The consequences of this is that although APC will compile, it will be linked against the wrong version of PHP.

After one updates their `php.ini` with the requisite `extension=apc.so`, as instructed by the conclusion of the `apc` installation, the following message will be found in their apache error file. (For Fink this is at `/sw/var/log/apache2/error.log`):

```
PHP Startup: apc: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20090626\nPHP    compiled with module API=20100525
```

The solution to this was to simply to `sudo pecl uninstall apc` then do `sudo fink install php5-dev`, then finally do `sudo pecl install apc`.

The final install of `apc` will use the include files added by `php5-dev` and all will be well.

Then you can confidently add `extension=apc.so` to `/sw/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

**One more thing**

Also note that my above instructions for for symlinking the `pcre.h` file have to be modified slightly to be:

`sudo ln -s /sw/include/pcre.h /sw/include/php5/ext/pcre`

The fact that `pecl` was messing with things in `/usr` and not a `/sw` directory should have tipped things off for me.